# How can I gain a wider audience for my writing pieces on Instagram?

Tags: social-media

For context I started writing short stories inspired by art on Instagram since January of this year. I constantly post three times a week, use popular hashtags, and comment on other post to gain an audience for it.

However, it appears it was in vain for I lack the amount of people reached on my account. I guess my question pertains more to authors and writers who have found ways to create a large audience for their content online. It would be great if someone had some advice or some tips on gaining more followers on Instagram.

Comment: I was surprised to find writers promoting their writing on Instagram, since it's visual-heavy. But here's an author blog giving advice on just that: https://www.almostanauthor.com/how-to-promote-your-writing-on-instagram/

Comment: Thank you for the link. Yeah, there are ways writers promote their writing. For me its just artwork and writing in 100 words or less a neat story.